# How do I fix colon problems in XML Conversion using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt

For some reason, colons in the tags of my XML files seem to be causing problems when I'm trying to render it in HTML format using XSL. I think it's the im: portion of the tag name, so are special characters just not allowed? Below is my xml.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="formatting.xsl" xmlns:im="im"?>
                <im:Command xmlns:im="im">
                   <im:CommandHdr>
                    <im:Name>John</im:Name>
                    <im:DisplayName>Jo</im:DisplayName>
               </im:CommandHdr>
            </im:Command>
```

Here is my XSL.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="/">
          <html>
          <body>
            <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="im:Command/im:CommandHdr">

              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="im:Name"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="im:DisplayName"/></td>
               </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>


            </table>
          </body>
          </html>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do I fix this problem.

Comment: You need to read up on namespaces in XML.  (See https://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html for example). The colon represents a namespace prefix. If you notice in your XML there is a namespace declaration of the form `xmlns:im="im"`. You just need to add that to your `xsl:stylesheet` too.

Comment: I tried adding "xmins:im="im"  and putting both the xml and xsl into  http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/. However, it still appears to throw me errors

Comment: Your XSLT is not well-formed either. You have closing `</table>` tag, but no opening one. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQp for a working example.

Comment: Fixed that up. I already searched working examples, but none I found had a colon in them.

Comment: Just search for "XSLT namespaces" on StackOverflow and you will find thousands of posts on the subject. Or if you want the information presented in a more organized way, read a book on XSLT. You absolutely need to understand namespaces before you do any more coding. (Learning from example code is not a good way to understand the underlying concepts.)